# Reusage of HttpClient instance in my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.8. In doing so, I'm consuming APIs from three separate partners. Each time an API call is made, an new instance of the `HttpClient` is created in the controller and invoked via an ajax call from the view page.

My question is that, even though we can develop using third-party packages like UNITY, we are unable to create dependency injection because this is an ASP.NET MVC application rather than an ASP.NET Core application.

How can I accomplish reusing a `HttpClient` instance across my program instead of utilizing dependency injection?

Due to the fact that the majority of articles mentioned that bad performance and socket exhaustion result from establishing new `HttpClient` instances. This is my API call code and also consider this API will be called lot throughout the day.

Code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                        | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                        | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                        | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelObj, settings);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
var bytecontent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

response = client.PostAsync(URL,bytecontent).Result;
```

I need to reuse `HttpClient` instance throughout my application without using Dependency Injection container in ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a pattern like the Singleton pattern to manage and reuse the `HttpClient` instance across your application.

Create a static class that manages the `HttpClient` instance:

```
public static class HttpClientHelper
{
    private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> httpClientInstance = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() =>
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // Set your desired SecurityProtocol
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        return httpClient;
    });

    public static HttpClient GetInstance()
    {
        return httpClientInstance.Value;
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller or wherever you make API calls, you can use this `HttpClientHelper` class to get the singleton `HttpClient` instance:

```
var client = HttpClientHelper.GetInstance();
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelObj, settings);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
var bytecontent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = client.PostAsync(URL, bytecontent).Result;
```

Please note that above code can help issues associated with creating multiple instances, but you have to handle the `HttpClient` properly, including managing its lifetime and ensuring proper disposal when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Mohanty. Why should I need to dispose those instance and if I need to dispose, HttpClientHelper  doesn't inherit IDisposable and If controller gets disposed then client instance gets disposed, so it also similar to creating new instance right?. If I am wrong, please correct me. Thank You.

Comment: The reason for properly disposing the `HttpClient` instance is to release the underlying resources associated with it, such as sockets, connections, etc., and to avoid potential issues like socket exhaustion. Disposing `HttpClient` is crucial, especially if your application makes a large number of API calls or if it's a long-running application.

Comment: Thanks for replying, But I have one doubt when we Disposed `HttpClient` instance then it also same like creating new instance for each request. In my scenario we will call API on daily basis, So if we constantly Dispose `HttpClient` then it also lead to socket exhaustion. What is the solution either disposing and recreating new instance is better or using same `HttpClient`  without disposing? how do I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `HttpClientFactory` to reuse clients.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: HttpClientFactory is .net core right?

Comment: It is not part of .NET Core. It is shipped via NuGet as separate packages.

Comment: Check [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection *is* possible in ASP.NET MVC. Implement [IControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory) and register it with [SetControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder.setcontrollerfactory):

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(myFactory);
```

You can use an existing third-party DI Container like Castle Windsor or AutoFac to implement the interface, or better yet, [write it yourself](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di). This gives you [full control over object lifetime](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/03/compile-time-lifetime-matching), which will enable you to reuse a single `HttpClient` instance across multiple Controllers.

Use normal Constructor Injection whenever you need the `HttpClient` instance.

For more details, see [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/diidn), which is freely included as an electronic book with the later edition [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://blog.ploeh.dk/dippp).